# Integral curves and ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find a first-order differential equation having the given family ofcurves as integral curves to that one: all circles through the points $(1, 1)$ and $(-1,-1)$?

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we suppose that the center of circle is $(a,b)$ and the radius is $r$. then we have the equation of the circle:
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2=C$$
here $C$ is a constant. Because the circle pass the two points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$, then we have the equations:
$$\left\{\matrix{(1-a)^2+(1-b)^2=C\\(1+a)^2+(1+b)^2=C}\right.$$
solve it we have $\left\{\matrix{a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{C-2}{2}}\\b=-a}\right.$.

Substitute $a$ and $b$ wtih the solutions, we have the equation of circle:
$$(x\mp\sqrt{\frac{C-2}{2}})^2+(y\pm\sqrt{\frac{C-2}{2}})^2=C$$
the range of $C$ is $C\geq2$. Simplify this equation:
$$\frac{x^2+y^2-2}{x-y}=\pm\sqrt{2(C-2)}$$
differential it(the right term will be $0$, because it is a constant) to have the first order differential equation.